# Nested for loop in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a table that is created from Lists of different sizes.
I have a list of Cars `List<Car>`. So in the header I want to place the names of the different companies which I did.

Then I have a `List<List<CarSales>>` and not all Cars exist in each carSales.
So I want to iterate through the List of List of each tr (also OK)
and then I want to iterate in the td though the List and place the CarSales.sales in the correct td where CarSales.mark=Car.makr of the header.

So if `List<Cars>` is (I mean Cars.mark)

```
[BMW, MERCEDES,FIAT]
```

And `List<List<CarSales>>` is (I mean object that have mark and sales inside)

```
[[BMW:5,FIAT:10],[MERCEDES:12]]
```

I want a table with:

```
BMW - MERCEDES - FIAT

 5  -    0     -  10

 0  -   12     -  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do that... but you can make the markup so much simpler if `List<List<CarSales>>` was instead a `List<Map<String, Integer>>` instead (where the key is the mark, and the value is the sales).  Then you could have something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th th:each="car: ${cars}" th:text="${car.mark}" />
  </tr>

  <tr th:each="sale: ${carSales}">
    <td th:each="car: ${cars}" th:text="${sale.get(car.mark)} ?: 0" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to go with your original structure, something like this might work, but it's more confusing to maintain:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th th:each="car: ${cars}" th:text="${car.mark}" />
  </tr>

  <tr th:each="sales: ${carSales}">
    <td th:each="car: ${cars}" th:with="sale=${sales.^[mark==#root.car.mark]}" th:text="${sale?.sales} ?: 0" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you explain the th:text? what is the sale?.sale

Comment: @kyrpav in the expression `sale?.sales`,  `?.` is the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation).  It just means if `sale` is null then the whole expression will return null, rather than try and resolve `sale.sales` (which would normally throw an null pointer exception.